nodemon Internal watch failed: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
I am running on macOS Sequoia 15.0. I constantly get:
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch.


I am running nodemon is the root of the project/backend directory Directory structure Error
This process creates a file named 8080, ? in the root of backend. I have to delete this file before I can restart nodemon.
I used to be able to run nodemon without any issues on this mac with os 14.x and then suddenly I started getting this error, which will not let me proceed with my project. It may have happened after some minor os 14.x update, I don't know. However I upgraded to Sequoia just yesterday, hoping that it might solve the problem but there has been no change.

I have looked in forums and have not been able to find a solution. Mostly what I have seen is people running nodemon few directories above where their server.js or index.js is located which I understand makes nodemon watch for all changes down directory structure. In my case that is not true, I am running nodemon in the same directory where my server.js is located, so I assume there is no overhead that way.
Here is my server.js:
// server.js

require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('./mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');

// Get App
const app = require('./app');

// Get Port
const port = process.env.PORT;

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Start App if Mongoose is connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  try {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is Running on ${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

function graceful() {
  mongoose.connection.close(() => {
    console.log('MongoDB connection closed.');
    process.exit(0);
  });
}

process.on('SIGTERM', graceful);
process.on('SIGINT', graceful);

